# Ubuntu VM won't start with 2 or more CPU cores

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu

I have an virtualized ubuntu server 16.04.4 instance (from `osboxes.org`) that I run with virtual box.

It runs smoothly with a single core, but as soon as I add another cpu it won't start up:
[image: Freeced screen]
The exact point when the system *freezes* (like shown in the screenshot above) changes from one start to another.

Here are my current settings:
[image: Settings 1]
[image: Settings 2]

I tried different numbers of cpus. IO-APIC is active as found on other sources. Nothing changed here. Thanks for your help

**Update**

- I'm running this on my laptop, HyperV is enabled.
- Processor is Intel i7-4700MQ (4 cores, 8 threads)
- I have 16gb of ddr3 ram
- I have installed the current stable version of Virtual Box, 5.2.8

Comment: What version of VirtualBox are you using? What CPU do you have? If your CPU is a dual-core (and 4 threads), of course you can't assign both physical cores to the guest.

Comment: @TiagoCaldeira You can assign as many threads as you have physically available. So actually assigning 4 threads of a 2-core CPU is allowed.

Comment: @Karl - You need to provide us hardware information.  Edit your question to include this required information into the body of your question.

Comment: @gronostaj My bad then. But the host machine need CPU too, it couldn't break your system by assigning all threads to the guest OS?

Comment: As @Ramhound says, and also check if you have the virtualization options enabled in the BIOS (VT-x or Hyper-V).

Comment: If you set the value between 2 and 4 what happens?  Anything over 4 isn’t supported by your hardware.

Comment: I tried all settings from 2 to 4 cores, but everytime the same result... More than 4 shows me an 'invalid settings'-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new vm, using the same image.

I added 4 cores initially and everything works fine. I even can remove and add cores now without any issues.